# Object doesn't support property or method "_super" in igGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I have used `infragistics` `igGrid` in my application but I am getting `javascript` error

> Object doesn't support property or method "_super"

I know this can be avoided but I want to give it fake implementation (or real answer, may be adding some missing reference) for some reasons. I tried following but not working.

```
var _super = function(a,s,d,f,g,h) {
}
```

I have wrote above code before referencing `igGrid` JS libraries.

In code, `_super` has variable number of arguments when calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably referencing a version of jQuery UI that still doesn't have `_super` and `_superApply` implemented. Try referencing the latest version and the error should go away.

https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6861

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to use `_super` out of scope. You can use `_super` in the objects scope like this :

```
(function ($) {

    $.ig.RPCDataSource = $.ig.RPCDataSource || $.ig.RESTDataSource.extend({

    _processJsonResponse: function (data, context) {
            try {
               console.log('my special preprocessing');
               return this._super(data, context);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
                // my special error handling
            } 
        },
   });
}(jQuery));
```

**UPDATE**
`_super` is a method from the [jQuery widget factory](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_super). iG controls are built upon j[Query Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/). Therefore `_super` is defined in jQuery widget.

Comment: I am not using super anywhere, library is using it internally. But it is not defined anywhere